# how to Export variables from shell script in a different user into current user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I have two user test1 and test2 I have some variables to be exported from sample.sh in test1. I want to export the values from test1 sample.sh into my test2 which is a current user I am in:

```
# sample.sh
export test="test1"
echo "hi"
export test2="test2"
```

I have tried this command:

```
su -test1 -c  ". /data/home/test1/.sample"
```

`echo` is working and printing in my current user which is test2. But when I try `printenv` I cant see any test or test2 in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of *export* exports variables into current session. Obviously, when you log out it will disappear. If you want to export it permanently, you should modify some profile files, like:

```
 /home/test2/.bashrc
 /home/test2/.bash_profile
```

So you can append those variables to this file. (cat my_env **>>** /home/test2/.bashrc)

Comment: What should I do if I want to export those variables temporarily. Whenever user logs in it should ask for all env for ex. Env1 in test1 env3 in test3. If I select env2 then it should execute that env3 and export values in env3.sh which is in test3 to test2 which is my current user